# How do I solve QEMU and HAXM portable launch issues?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, haxm, portable-applications

I am having issues with HAXM and QEMU portable launch in Winodws. I have tried running the apps with admin permissions but that didn't solve my issue.

Vbox works fine. I am trying to create a portable QEMU but without good acceleration it's WAY to slow.

```
:\DELETE\QEMU_INSTALLED>qemu-system-x86_64.exe  -hda ./debian.qcow2 -boot d -cdrom debian-10.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso   -m 1024   -usb  -cpu max   -net nic,model=virtio -accel hax
Failed to open the HAX device!
Open HAX device failed
Failed to get Hax capability:6u
No accelerator found.
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -accel hax: failed to initialize hax: Invalid argument

C:\DELETE\QEMU_INSTALLED>..\haxm-windows_v7_6_1\haxm_check.exe
VT support -- yes
NX support -- yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installed haxm-windows_v7_6_1 intelhaxm-android.exe